# Retrieving linear model equations using qplot and stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting nonlinear relationships with qplot,e.g.,

```
qplot(log(a),log(b)+stat_smooth(method="lm",formula="y~poly(x,2)",se=FALSE)
```

and get a plot of my data with (what appears to be) an accurate nonlinear regression curve. Is there a way to retrieve the equation (i.e., the coefficients) for the plotted curve?

Answer (score 5):

Could you simply call the `lm` function?

```
summary(lm(log(a) ~ poly(log(b),2), data = yourdata))
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to override this: "Error in poly(log(Brain_weight_g, 2)) :  missing values are not allowed in 'poly'"

Comment: You might want to scrub your data set prior to running the regression; newdata = yourdata[complete.cases(yourdata$Brain_weight_g),].  The regression will throw out any regressor rows with an NA value for you; it appears poly() will not.

Comment: Thanks again. The data cleaning worked, but the output of the summary was "Length   Class    Mode 
      3 formula    call "   which isn't very helpful, because I would like to compare the qplot curve to the one I'm getting from nls(). If you have any further suggestions, I'd be grateful.